# LINQtoCsv missing reference after upgraded C# .net application from EF 4.7.2 to EF core 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linqtocsv

After upgrading from C# .net application from EntityFrame `4.7.2` to EntityFramework Core 8,  I noticed that using LINQtoCSV reference is missing. My build failed with:

> *Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CsvColumnAttribute' could not
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   Mlc.Reinsurance.DataTransferObjects C:\MLCREDSHA-7693RIDZConvert3\red\Red\Source\Mlc.Reinsurance.DataTransferObjects\AccountStatementAdjustment\AccountStatementOldDTO.cs   57  Active*

Please advise what is the correct installation. Also, how to add the reference to .Net Core 8?

I tried installing LINCtoCSV version `1.5.0` and `1.6.0` got the following errors.

```
PM> NuGet\Install-Package LinqToCsv -Version 1.5.0
```

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
> 'LinqToCsv.1.5.0' with respect to project 'Portals\REDWebSite',
> targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2' NuGet\Install-Package :
> Package 'LinqToCsv 1.5.0' is not found in the following primary
> source(s):  'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json,C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'. Please verify all  your online
> package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified
> correctly. At line:1 char:1
>
> - NuGet\Install-Package LinqToCsv -Version 1.5.0
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallP
>   ackageCommand   Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.7180270

```
PM> NuGet\Install-Package Threenine.LinqToCsv -Version 1.6.0
```

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
> 'Threenine.LinqToCsv.1.6.0' with respect to project
> 'Portals\REDWebSite', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'
> NuGet\Install-Package : Package 'Threenine.LinqToCsv 1.6.0' is not
> found in the following primary source(s):
> 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json,C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> SDKs\NuGetPackages'. Please verify all  your online package sources
> are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly. At
> line:1 char:1
>
> - NuGet\Install-Package Threenine.LinqToCsv -Version 1.6.0
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallP
>   ackageCommand   Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.4114128

Comment: Have you update the target framework of your application? EF Core 8 is only compatible with .NET 8. From your nuget output, it seems it's trying to restore the other packages with target .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2. Are they compatible with .NET 8?

Comment: .NET Core and .NET Framework are different runtime environments, therefore you can't install a package that targets .NET Framework to your .NET Core project. see here for supported frameworks for the package you wish to install: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: I found this package which seems to be a port of that library that supports .NET Core framework, perhaps it will work for you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Threenine.LinqToCsv